# Is it possible to use ActiveSync to access my folders in Thunderbird when using the new Outlook.com?

Tags: thunderbird, activesync

Originally, it seemed as if it was not possible to use Hotmail with Thunderbird in an IMAP (or IMAP like fashion) without some hacks (the WebMail plugin, etc.) and it seemed the best method was to use a Gmail account configured as IMAP and read in the Hotmail account as a POP3.  Of course, this eliminates any sort of access to folders on the Hotmail account.

Now that Microsoft is toting the new `Outlook.com` moniker/platform (and I have switched over) I have heard that the support for ActiveSync is improved, and that this can be used to access folders in the account from another client.  I haven't found a plugin for Thunderbird that will make this seamless.

Is there a method that I'm overlooking to accomplish this?  Is there another desktop client besides Outlook proper that can work with ActiveSync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, none of the released versions of Outlook work with Exchange Activesync, which was originally developed for mobile applications.  Outlook uses a different Exchange protocol with lots more features.

Outlook 2013 is the first version of Outlook that can connect via ActiveSync, but it's still in beta.  The built-in mail client in Windows 8 also has native ActiveSync capability, but Windows 8 is not yet available to the general public.

The developer of the ExQuilla plugin suggests that licensing fees may be the primary issue preventing Thunderbird plugins from adding ActiveSync:

> ActiveSync is a different technology than the “Exchange Web Services” that is used by ExQuilla. ExQuilla will not do ActiveSync, nor will it really be of any help with HotMail. Sorry.
>
> Also, ActiveSync has significant licensing fees associated with applications that use it, plus it is primarily focused on phone users, so it is unlikely to be a viable technology for a Thunderbird addon. Sorry.
>
> http://mesquilla.com/2012/01/31/exquilla-microsoft-exchange-server-for-thunderbird-beta-version-released/

Comment: I never updated this, but I've been using the Outlook 2013 preview to this end quite successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use Windows Live Mail 2012 from Windows Essentials 2012 to sync with the new Outlook.com